# não consigo compilar programa em Java

Tags: java

Já tentei baixar o JDK 8 x86 bits mudar o pach e nada o código continua dando o erro...
The selection cannot be lauched, and there are no recents launches[image: erro]

Answer (score 1):

Ta faltando o static no seu método

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

Comment: vlw mano eu n vi isso eu tava perdendo a minha cabeça

Comment: se resolveu valida ai ;)